# How do I know when to use support classes?

Tags: android

I'm newbie in development for Android platform and trying to understand how do I know or predict when I have to use support classes? This is probably stupid question, but let me give you a simple example. Let's say I want to add a sharing functionality to my application so I go to DAC and see there an [example](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) of how this can be done. I read the manual carefully and see the note about limitations i.e.

> Note:  ShareActionProvider is available starting with API Level 14 and higher

It seems this is OK for me since the minSdkVersion is set to 14 in my app. I copy-paste that snippet to my project, launch the application and... it crashes with the following error:

```
05-21 12:42:07.638: E/AndroidRuntime(25291): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
```

I update my sources to use the following code instead the one which I found in documentation:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
```

Starting app. At first sight it's working but instead of share icon I can see text SHARE in the ActionBar. Humm, after googling around I replace the following line in menu layout

```
android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
```

to

```
app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
```

Hooray! Finally I've got what I want!

This is not the first time I experience such obstacles while learning the Android platform so I'm trying to find whether there is any rule of thumb which will help me to predict such situations?

As for support library, not that I've added it for purpose. This library was added automatically when I created project in Android Studio. After playing a little bit with Android Studio I've figured out that it automatically adds it to the project unless the min SDK is set to latest 21 or 22 versions. So technically almost all applications have to use this library to be run on wider range of Android devices. If this is true then why Android training and guide materials don't use support classes in examples?

Any help and advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can find a good explanation in this [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22461676/1280702

Comment: There is no general rule of thumb. But once you get a feel for how Android works everything will begin to make sense (at least most of the time). Most things are pretty self explanatory when you know what to look for, for example the fix for the error you mention in your question is explained right there in the message of the exception: `This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()`

Comment: As you have said, you should always include support libraries. It's always better to not to use support methods/classes if you have the choice, but sometimes is inavoidable. For example, CardView was included in v 5.0 but you have to use it through support libraries, even if you are developing for v 5.1 (which is nice because in this way you can use it in 4.4, etc.)

Comment: @Androbito , I saw this question and answer for it. It perfectly explains which version of support library I need to use in order to support different ranges or API, however it doesn't explain to me why I have to use specific classes instead of those I see in examples. My understanding is that it's up to me whether I want to use this lib depending on what the min version of SDK I want to support. However as I said in real life I must to use this library almost every time. Therefore how can I understand that instead of getActionBar method I have to call getSupportActionBar?

Comment: @XaverKapeller, this is great thing about Android that I can see the solution for the problem in exception message itself. However I would be more happier if I can write working code at the first attempt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to find whether there is any rule of thumb which will help me to predict such situations

I have no idea what "such situations" are beyond the one that you have cited here.

In this specific case, the menu resource cited in the first step uses `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` instead of something like `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`. The latter is required if you are using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport. Hence, this sample must not be using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport.

There is little question that the documentation could be improved in this area, to either provide instructions for both action bar implementations, or to at least positively state which action bar implementation that they are using.

> So technically almost all applications have to use this library to be ran on wider range of Android devices.

No. Zero applications *have* to use `appcompat-v7` to be run on a wide range of Android devices, going all the way back to API Level 1.

However:

- If you want an action bar on devices running Android 1.x/2.x, you need an action bar backport, and `appcompat-v7` is the only currently maintained full-featured backport that I am aware of (given that ActionBarSherlock is deprecated)
- If you want to try to have a UI that resembles Material Design on devices running Android 4.4 and below, current editions of `appcompat-v7` do that as well

Comment: OK, it seems this is getting a bit clear for me. Looking back I can say that it seems all the problems I've faced were related to ActionBar usage. Another example of such situation I've met the other day was using method getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar(). The second one returns null if I use support ActionBar. So does that mean if I use something from support library e.g. ActionBar so for every little thing such as styling attributes, classes and methods I need to look for support analogs?

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich: "So does that mean if I use something from support library e.g. ActionBar so for every little thing such as styling attributes, classes and methods I need to look for support analogs?" -- yes, by and large. Backports like `appcompat-v7` are designed to have as similar an API as possible to the thing that they are back-porting. However, inevitably, there wind up being differences.

Comment: BTW, just want to comment that I didn't use ActionBar from support library for purpose. A code template for the activity was automatically generated by Android Studio when I've created my project. According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) I can easily use `android.app.ActionBar` instead of `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` and get rid of these problems so the question is why Android Studio used this template of Activity even if it knew I set the min SDK to 14?

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich: "why Android Studio used this template of Activity even if it knew I set the min SDK to 14?" -- because that's what their templates call for. This is one of the reasons why I don't use the new-project and new-activity wizards in Android Studio.