# Difference between Fragment Manager and Support Fragment Manager

Tags: android, android-fragments

These two classes are clearly related. Is `SupportFragmentManager` used for `Fragments` generated using `FragmentTransaction`, while the "regular" `FragmentManager` is used exclusively to test `Fragments` generated using `.xml` files? If not, what is the difference? If so, why are two separate classes necessary to do this? Doesn't that just add extra complexity to the code base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of Fragments came only after API 11...in order to support those functions in older API version we use Support Libs... I think you have completely mis understood the concept of using support libs.. Do have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22461543/1625788) question and a quick Google will help u out